# mysql query return only if number of rows is more than zero

Tags: mysql, count, return, rows

How can I change this query to only return rows that return more than 0 rows?

I need to combine these two queries. I need to return rows where the second query returns at least 1 row.

```
    SELECT albumData.* 
       FROM albumData 
      WHERE userID='$id' 
        AND state='0' 
   ORDER BY date DESC


  SELECT photos.photo 
    FROM albums, photos 
   WHERE albums.userID = '$id' 
     AND albums.photoID = photos.id 
     AND albums.albumID = $albumID 
ORDER BY photos.id DESC LIMIT 6;
```

**EDIT** add useful information from comments:

> Table albumData containers unique rows, for each user, for each photo
>   album they have set up, this is where I want to return the number of
>   rows from initially. However I want to compare the id in albumData to
>   albumID is albums table, if the number of rows with
>   albums.albumID=albumData.id is more than one, then return those rows.

Comment: edit your question and provide table structure pls...

Comment: `to only return rows that return more than 0 rows.` I dont get it please give more info

Comment: structure with TYPE pls... Like id INT...

Comment: If you mean in a language like `in php`... you can use the `count` to calculate the number of rows returned. It will return only when it has rows to return!

Comment: I was actually trying to do this wrong, I need to edit the first query, however I need to count the number of rows as the second query would return.

Comment: @footy, yes that works fine when I do that, I was just attempting to do this all on the mysql server, as it is faster in the long run.

Comment: Don't get your problem exactly...

Comment: so you have 3 tables? albums, photos, albumsdata? connected throw albums.photoID = photos.id  and albums.albumID=albumsData.albumID?

Comment: Table albumData containers unique rows, for each user, for each photo album they have set up, this is where I want to return the number of rows from initially. However I want to compare the id in albumData to albumID is albums table, if the number of rows with albums.albumID=albumData.id is more than one, then return those rows.

Comment: almost correct, the last one is this:

albums.albumID=albumsData.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next try .. if I understand the problem right

```
SELECT photos.photo 
FROM albums
INNER JOIN photos on albums.photoID = photos.id 
INNER JOIN albumData ON albumData.id = albums.albumID
WHERE albums.userID = '$id' 
  and albums.albumID = $albumID 
  and albumData.state = '0'
ORDER BY photos.id DESC LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: That seems like it should work, however it's not returning anything.

Comment: still isn't working, you had a couple columns the wrong names, i changed them to what they should but, yet still doesn't return anything. (i edited your answer to correct rows, im not sure if it will show or not though)

Comment: what isnt working .. you got no output? or what .. can post your php code to?

Comment: correct, there is no output. if i just try to output id in a while(mysql_fetch_array()) loop nothing is returned.

Comment: try to replace $id and $albumId in the SQL statement with valid numbers like 1 and 1 and try it again ..

Comment: Still nothing.. (and by the way, I noticed the query is a little wrong, you have albumsData, not albumData) but fixing that didn't do anything.

Comment: can you please provide some example data in your quest with the wanted output .. that would be the easies way to see what you have and what you want

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to have gotten my script working on accident, ha.. Trying to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume your getting some kind of error..
if your trying to prevent a null recordset:

use someything like this

```
$getPhotosq = "
SELECT photos.photo FROM albums, photos 
WHERE albums.userID='$id' 
AND albums.photoID=photos.id 
AND albums.albumID=$albumID 
ORDER BY photos.id DESC LIMIT 6"; 

$rs = mysql_query($getPhotosq);
if($rs) {
 /// DO THE CODE
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `mysql_query(mysql_query(...))`?

Comment: I was actually trying to do this wrong, I need to edit the first query, however I need to count the number of rows as the second query would return.

Comment: $rs will evaluate to true even on empty resultset as long as the query runs without error, you need `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: yeah, using mysql_num_rows works fine for this, however I am trying to keep as much in my query as I can, but I didn't realize this would be so difficult, more so to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems **CORRECT**.

Below might be problem...

There are **NO** records that equal `$id` **AND** `$albumID`. Please check this manually first and execute query again...

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT albumData.* 
    FROM albumData, albums 
   WHERE albumData.userID='$id' 
     AND albumData.state='0' 
     AND albums.state='0' 
     AND albumData.id=albums.albumID 
GROUP BY albums.albumID 
ORDER BY albums.date DESC
```